# Finding a unique distance function

Tags: analysis

I want to make a metric function on $\Bbb R (reals) which has these  characterizations:

$\Bbb Q$ (rationals) is not dense in $\Bbb R$ for this metric function.
I've really got stuck on how to start making this meter,does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, 
$$ d(x,y)=\begin{cases}|x-y|&\text{if }x,y\in\Bbb Q\text{ or }x,y\notin\Bbb Q\\
1+|x|+|y|&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: This is not a metric, as $d(\pi,\pi)\neq0$

Comment: @Stan Tendijck, why is that? By definition if $x,y\notin\mathbb{Q}$ then $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. So $d(\pi,\pi)=0$.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right

Answer (score 1):

Define the trivial metric $d(x,y)=\delta_{xy}$, which means $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\ne y$ and $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$. Can you see why $\mathbb{Q}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$ with this metric?